# Windows Phone 8 creating new screen

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, screen

I stuck on creating a new screen on windows phone 8. do I create a new XAML file and link the main one and the now one using a button? Is there a function to create a screen?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean a `new screen`?  Do you mean a new page?  If so, then you want to create a new XAML page and Add it to the project.

To navigate from one page to another page you can use a button or a link or whatever event of your choosing like so

```C#
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YOUR_NEW_PAGE.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

This will navigate to YOUR_NEW_PAGE.xaml, this will also push your previous page onto the Navigation stack.  So when you press the hardware `Back Button` it will return to the previous page.

---

If you just want a new Section then there are many ways to create a "New Section" on the same page.

See example of Pivot App Template (uses the Pivot Control) and Panorama App Template (uses the Panorama Control).  With these controls you just swipe left and right to go to another sub section of the Control (see the Settings page on the Windows Phone and the News/Finance App on the Windows Phone for examples)

---

Useful links:

[MSDN : How to create a pivot app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941103%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
[MSDN : How to create a panorama app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941109%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way to create a new page.
All you need to do is:
1. Right click on your project.
2. Hover to 'Add' 
3. Click New Page 
You are done :)
This is the code if you want to navigate to your new page.

```
  this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(NEW_PAGE));
```

Comment: You need to retag your question to window phone 8.1, if this is the solution you were looking for.